# Perl code re-engineering with multithreading for continuous Ping records generated per host

Tags: multithreading, perl, optimization, ping, multitasking

A very happy new year to all :D

I have written a piece of code in perl which works fine but I am looking foreward to enhance that code exploiting features like Multithreading and process forking.
Code is designed to work for the followin tasks:

1. Continuosly record ping for several servers provided in list.
2. MAintain and write logs for each pinged host seperately.
3. Display Live stats in real time command window.

Complete code is:

```
#!/user/perl/bin 
use strict;
use Net::Ping;
use Time::HiRes;
use IO::Handle;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

#       AUTHOR  :       Avi Mehenwal
#       PURPOSE :       Continuous ping check with PERL iThreads (interpreted threads)
#       DATE    :       10th-Jan-2013

sub Ping {

#Filer handle generation and open log file for writing in append mode.
#creating ping object to check ping response
#Writing Ping results in logs and command window for Real time analysis
#Close file after logs are witten

    my ($host , $protocol) = @_;
    chop $host;
    open my $log, '>>', "Ping_$host.txt" or die "Cannot create log file: $!";
    $log->autoflush;                                                          #autoflusing to stop output stream buffering.      
    my $p = Net::Ping->new($protocol) or die "Cannot create new Net::Ping object : $!";
    $p->hires;
    my ($ret, $duration, $ip) = $p->ping($host);
    if ($ret=='1')
     {    my $event = sprintf "%s\t%s is alive $protocol (packet RTT: %.3fms)\n",
                             scalar localtime, $host, $duration;
          print STDOUT $event;
          print $log $event;
          sleep(1);  #sleep only when ping is continuous    
      }
    else
     {    my $event = sprintf "%s\t%s is UNAVAILABLE (Timedout/lost $protocol request)\n",
                                            scalar localtime, $host;
          print STDOUT $event;
          print $log $event;               
     }
    close $log; 
}

my @hostip = qw(10.98.10.253, 10.112.114.10, 10.112.114.11);
STDOUT->autoflush;
print "****************************************************************************\n\ncPING-CHECK -v2.0 By-Avi Mehenwal\n\n";
print "Kindly enter the protocol to be used by cPing-Probe : tcp / udp / icmp ...\n";
my $protocol = <STDIN>;
chomp $protocol;
if($protocol eq "icmp") {
 print "\nWARNING:For cPing-Probe to use icmp protocol kindly run the program in administrative command prompt\ncPing-Probe v2.0will now exit ...";
 sleep(10);
 exit;
}      

while(1)      {
 foreach my $thost (@hostip) {
   Ping($thost,$protocol);
 }     
}     

#END
```

Now I was thinking to improve my code using one thread per ip host which would check ping and write logs without affecting other host ip threads. For this I tryed several codes but I found some success with this code below:

```
my @hostip = qw(10.98.10.253, 10.112.114.10, 10.112.114.11);
STDOUT->autoflush;
print "****************************************************************************\n\ncPING-CHECK -v2.0 By-Avi Mehenwal\n\n";
print "Kindly enter the protocol to be used by cPing-Probe : tcp / udp / icmp ...\n";
my $protocol = <STDIN>;
chomp $protocol;
if($protocol eq "icmp") {
 print "\nWARNING:For cPing-Probe to use icmp protocol kindly run the program in administrative command prompt\ncPing-Probe v2.0will now exit ...";
 sleep(10);
 exit;
}      

while(1)
{   my $thr;
foreach my $thost (@hostip) 
{       $thr = threads->new(Ping,$thost,$protocol) or die "Cannot Create thread : $!";  #seperate thread for each IP
    Ping($thost,$protocol);
    }
    if($thr->is_joinable())
     {       $thr->join(); 
             print STDOUT "Thread joined\n";   }
    else
      {      $thr->detach();
             print STDOUT "Thread detached\n"; }     
}     

#END
```

But this code is suffering from some unwanted symptoms for which I need experts help.

- Why do I have a log file named Ping_ generated and logs written to it ! Ideally log file per host is required. I fail to understand the trick here.
- Is my code really doing multitasking with parallel running threads for each host ? How I can I check or be sure of that ?
- IS there any better way of doing my job ?
- IS there any additional feature you can think I could add to my code ?

Thanks everyone in advance :D
Cheers !!

-Avi Mehenwal

Comment: Are you using Ping-Probe for your ping? Have you checked the Ping-Probe documentation to see what logging it does?

Comment: No I am not using Ping-Probe for my ping. I am using Perl module Net::Ping to send icmp echo requests.
And yes sir I have read its documentation :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do not use threads at all; in Perl, they're evil.
2. Do not use `fork` on I/O-intensive tasks.

[AnyEvent::Ping](https://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent%3a%3aPing) seems to do exactly what you're trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use common::sense
use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::Ping;
 
my $c = AnyEvent->condvar;
 
my $ping = AnyEvent::Ping->new;
 
$ping->ping('google.com', 1, sub {
    my $result = shift;
    print "Result: ", $result->[0][0],
      " in ", $result->[0][1], " seconds\n";
    $c->send;
});
 
$c->recv;
```

Comment: Thanks @creaktive !! And yes indeed AnyEvent::Ping is the module which works similar to my code. IS there any way I can use Multitasking/threading in my program ? I need functional code for my understanding and concept clearity. Thanks again for your genuin help buddy